# Setting a directory using "system-name" on Elisp

Tags: emacs

Indeed, I'm not fluent when dealing with Elisp. Anyhow: I use the same Emacs config file, but as usual, there are small differences when I'm in home or in the office, I don't know if is possible to define my working dir with a code like this:

```
(setq my-dir (if (string= system-name "hp-pavilion23")
                 (progn (message "/home/manuel/entwicklung/lisp/"))
               (progn (message "/home/mmontoya/projects/chipotle/"))))

(setq default-directory my-dir)
```

Comment: 1. The `progn`s here do nothing. 2. `message` returns `nil` (and so does wrapping it with `progn`). 3. So the first `setq` sets variable `my-dir` to `nil`. 4. The second `setq` then sets `default-directory` to `nil`. What is it that you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Let me guess. You want `default-directory` to be either `~/manuel/entwicklung/lisp` or `~/mmontoya/projects/chipotle` depending on your `system-name`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't know if is possible to define my working dir...

Yes, you can. You just need to go in a simple way, as **Lisp** is designed to be *simple*.

```
(if (string= system-name "hp-pavilion23")
    (setq my-dir "/home/manuel/entwicklung/lisp/")
  (setq my-dir "/home/mmontoya/projects/chipotle/"))

(setq default-directory my-dir)
```

However, why even bother with that extra `my-dir`? Just set `default-directory` where you want.

```
;; Somewhere in your ~/.emacs
(if (string= system-name "hp-pavilion23")
    ;; Set default-directory here.
    (setq default-directory "/home/manuel/entwicklung/lisp/")
  (setq default-directory "/home/mmontoya/projects/chipotle/"))
```

Note that `default-directory` is a variable automatically provided from Emacs. So make sure the change doesn't harm any other behaviour.

Comment: And of course you can further reduce that to `(setq default-directory (if condition "foo" "bar"))` if you prefer.

Comment: Note that `default-directory` is buffer-local.  You probably only want to set the local value, but in case you want to set the default value, use `setq-default`.